# Visualization of stack and heap for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, heap-memory, stack-memory

I wish to better understand the use of stack and heap in JavaScript. Are there any tools that will let me see exactly what is on both the stack and heap at any given moment in my client-side javascript (or Node.js if need be)?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome developers tools lets you inspect heap snapshots:

[image: chrome dev tools profiler]